# evenly distribute an arbitrary number of elements in an HTML container

Tags: html, css, stylus

Want to be able to

1. set the width of a container element in an HTML element arbitrarily
2. given X subelements in the container, distribute those subelements evenly within the container

like so:

[image]

Would like to know how to do this both in vanilla CSS and also in Stylus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```
.container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

You can use space-between or space-around.